# C++ main.cpp Compilation error

Tags: c++, compilation

(Beginner) My *main.cpp* is giving me trouble compiling, here's what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Test.h"

int main(){

bool add, sub, transp, mult, multScal;

//Checks each operation at once, some should fail each time depending on contents of C.txt
add=TestAdd();

sub=TestSubtr();

transp=TestTranspose();

mult=TestMultMatrices();

multScal=TestMultByScalar();

cout <<"Add success: " <<add <<'\n' <<"Subtract success: " <<sub <<'\n' 
<<"Transpose success: " <<transp <<'\n' <<"Multiplying 2 matrices success: " 
<<mult <<'\n' <<"Multiplying by Scalar success: " <<multScal <<"\nThanks for playing!";
}
```

where *TestAdd()*, *TestSubtr()*, etc. are all found within *Test.h*. I'm getting an error for each, though, saying they are undefined for main.cpp. Any clues as to why?

Edit: here's my Test.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Matrix.h"
class Test{
public:
    bool TestAdd();
    bool TestSubtr();
    bool TestTranspose();
    bool TestMultMatrices();
    bool TestMultByScalar(); 


private:
    Matrix loadMatrix(std::string filename);
    bool compare(Matrix A, Matrix B);
};
```

Comment: what are the errors and how are the functions `TestAdd()` and `TestSubtr()` defined?

Comment: some should fail each time depending on contents of C.txt?  Is there a C.txt you should have included somewhere?  What is this comment referring to?

Comment: Is it in the same folder as you cpp file?

Comment: C.txt is read in within Test.cpp, it is called accordingly within each Test*somefunction*

Comment: @ChrisCM it's the same for each:

    main.cpp:12:16: error: 'TestSubtr' was not declared in this scope
  sub=TestSubtr();
                ^
main.cpp:14:23: error: 'TestTranspose' was not declared in this scope
  transp=TestTranspose();
                           ^

Comment: @user489041 It was, but I think it got left behind while copying the files to another location. It didn't make a difference though while including them

Comment: Post your Test.h file so we can see it.

Comment: You don't have those functions defined, only declared. You must define them. You can do as Oli_G suggests below.

Comment: Your error message is correct. They arent defined. All it knows is the prototype of the function. Not what/where the funtion is. Give them a definition.

Comment: They're defined within Test.cpp

Answer (score 2):

Try to put thoses simples functions definitions in Test.h :

```
bool TestAdd() {return true;}
bool TestSubtr() {return true;}
bool TestTranspose() {return true;}
bool TestMultMatrices() {return true;}
bool TestMultByScalar() {return true;}
```

Also make sure than Test.h is in the same folder as main.cpp. It should compile without errors.

Edit:

The problem you face is than all your tests functions are members of the class Test and cannot be called directly without creating an instance of the Test class. You can create an instance like this in main() :

```
Test myTest;
```

After that you can call your members functions like this within main() :

```
add = myTest.TestAdd();
```

Also, presently your functions are only declared in Test.h, but they have no content. Function content goes within brackets { }. Normally, you declare the function in the .h file and you put the function content in .cpp file. Hoewever, this is not mandatory and you can put content in the .h file.

To get your code to compile, replace your functions declarations by complete functions :

```
bool TestAdd();
```

becomes :

```
bool TestAdd(){return true;}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: They are defined, within Test.cpp...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a linker error. For each of your class you should add them as a source.

If you are using a gnu compiler here's a makefile for you:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -pedantic
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=main.cpp test.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=programname

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf *o programname
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a main like,

```
   int main(){

       bool add, sub, transp, mult, multScal;

       Test ObjTest;// Object for Test class created
       //Checks each operation at once, some should fail each time depending on contents of C.txt
       add=objTest.TestAdd(); //Accessing the member function using Object

       sub=objTest.TestSubtr();

       transp=objTest.TestTranspose();

       mult=objTest.TestMultMatrices();

       multScal=objTest.TestMultByScalar();

       cout <<"Add success: " <<add <<'\n' <<"Subtract success: " <<sub <<'\n' 
       <<"Transpose success: " <<transp <<'\n' <<"Multiplying 2 matrices success: " 
       <<mult <<'\n' <<"Multiplying by Scalar success: " <<multScal <<"\nThanks for laying!";
   }
```

Solution is you have to create an object of a class Test to access the member functions.

Hope this helps.